# SQL: How is this query getting executed when the inner subquery is returning multiple rows while I haven't used IN()?

Tags: sql

I have a table `emptable` and `EMPNO` is the primary key.

I run this query:

```
SELECT ename 
FROM emp 
WHERE ename = (SELECT MIN(ename) FROM emp);
```

and it returns this:

[image]

Since the inner subquery is returning two rows, and since I am not using `IN()`, shouldn't I get an error of subquery returning multiple rows, so how am I getting this output?

P.S.: Sorry for my horrible English

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: Also by default MIN() just grabs the minimum value, it doesnt return multiple values.

Comment: *SELECT MIN(ename) FROM emp* returns a single value so this query is perfectly valid.

Comment: To echo what Stu and I are saying, run the subquery by itself and youll see

Comment: @DougCoats , Well I was solving an assignment I had, it had three options 1. HELLO, HELLO, 2. HELLO and 3. Error, I choose option 3, since it was the wrong answer, I created this table myself, and ran that query as asked in the assignment, I was just wondering why it doesn't throw an error

Comment: As you can no doubt now see, the answer is `2`

Comment: @Stu , Well the answer is 1. HELLO HELLO, I ran it on ORACLE live sql, the output image I have linked in the main question, the second row where it shows  ENAME HELLO HELLO is the output

Comment: Ha - still looking just from the perspective of the subquery ;-)

Comment: You subquery only returns a single value because of the aggregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery:

```
SELECT MIN(ename) FROM emp
```

returns only 1 row with 1 column (it is called a **scalar** subquery) which has the value of the minimum `ename` of the table.

If you had used also a GROUP BY clause like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ename) FROM emp GROUP BY empno
```

then the subquery would return 2 rows, 1 for each `empno`.

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough while asking, the subquery is returning 2 rows, that's why I am confused, those two HELLO it is returning are from two rows, ROW 1: EMPNO: 1234 ENAME: HELLO and ROW 2: EMPNO:5678 ENAME: HELLO

Comment: @WaitWhat you mean that the query returns 2 rows, right? Because the subquery returns only 1 row. Run the subquery only.

Comment: I understand that MIN makes the subquery return only one row, but as I said in the image I have shared, it shows "2 rows selected", and the output is two HELLO's not one

Comment: @WaitWhat the output is the output of the query and not the subquery. In your table there are 2 rows with ename equal to the min ename of the table. The subquery returns the min ename and it is compared to all the enames in the table.

Comment: Oh silly me, thank you for that, now I understand, so the subquery is returning only one Hello, but the outer query has two ENAME with HELLO and that's why it is printing two HELLO's, got it!

Answer (score 0):

So subqueries are fun. Aside from using a sub query as something to select from, the general types are scalar or correlated.

**Scalar subqueries** can only return one value.

**Correlated subqueries** refer to something outside of the subquery (think EXISTS clause, as that is a kind of correlated subquery).

These two definitions are crude and not text book but explain them simply enough for now.

So your subquery is scalar and used for comparison. What makes it fit the rules for returning only one value is the MIN() function as MIN() only returns one value. If you did not use MIN(), then you would have to figure out another way to make it fit the rules of a scalar subquery. For example:

```
SELECT ename 
FROM emp e
WHERE ename = 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 ename 
        FROM emp 
        WHERE emp.ename=e.ename 
        ORDER BY emp.ename ASC
    );
```

This is a correlated scalar subquery, as the subquery refers to the e object from the outer query. You’ll notice I had to had TOP 1 because the sample data provided doesn’t give me any other unique columns for comparison, not doing so would caused the “you can only have one value returned from scalar subquery” error.

So to answer your question – the reason it does not error is because the sub query only returns one value. For each row of your result set, the ename equals to the MIN(ename). This is intended behavior.